# why is requestMIDIAccess working locally but not remote?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Playing around with this javascript library
https://www.w3.org/TR/webmidi/#introduction I got some basic functionality working and I was happily able to send midi notes to my syntheseizer and hear it working!..

However, when I wanted to try out the exact same javascript code, but hosted remotely, I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.navigator.requestMIDIAccess is not a function
```

My code can be boiled down to following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="test-result">MIDI test</h1>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            window.navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(
                x => document.getElementById("test-result").innerHTML = "success!",
                x => document.getElementById("test-result").innerHTML = "fail!"
            );
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does it work locally but not remote?

*I am using google-chrome and it is my impression that webmidi should be supported, although experimental https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MIDIAccess*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`navigator.requestMIDIAccess()` is only available [in a secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts/features_restricted_to_secure_contexts), which means your remote host must serve your resources via HTTPS.

Resources served from `localhost` [are considered to be in a secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts#When_is_a_context_considered_secure), whether delivered via HTTPS or HTTP.

Connect to your remote host using HTTPS instead of HTTP and that should resolve the problem.

Comment: I'm curious if there is an overview somewhere that explains which libraries require HTTPS and which that doesn't..?

Comment: @Michelrandahl it's usually documented on MDN, but this seems to be a relatively new API so contributors to the documentation probably haven't added those details yet. I'll see if I can find a reference to this for at least one of the other APIs though.

Comment: @Michelrandahl it turns out you can find Web MIDI in that first link, if you see my edited answer.

Comment: navigator.requestMIDIAccess() is only available in a secure context. Does that mean that I must create a self-signed ssl certificate on my ubuntu server 22.04 if I want to use web midi locally on my own server? Like this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: @PeterKarlsson if the server is running on your local machine then no. Just use localhost with HTTP and that's considered a secure context as well.